# Upgrade to zurb foundation 4.3 and Section now hidden on large screen size

Tags: zurb-foundation

I just upgraded from version 4.1 from a month or so back and suddenly my section (horozintal-nav) is being hidden on screen sizes above 768px.  Prior to the upgrade it would display as a horizontal nav above 768px and as an accordion on smaller screens.

I am using compass and sass.

I have also tried cutting and pasting their example code from their documentation into the top of my page and I get the same behaviour with that as well.

The CSS that hides the control...

```
  /* line 49, ../../../../../lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.1/scss/foundation/components/_section.scss */
  [data-section='horizontal-nav']:not([data-section-resized]):not([data-section-small-style]), .section-container.horizontal-nav:not([data-section-resized]):not([data-section-small-style]) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Also had this issue, your fix below helped. Does seem like a bit of a hack though, I'd imagine the JS is supposed to add one of these data attributes automatically, therefore unhiding everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I just needed to add data-section-resized attribute to my container.

```
<div data-section="horizontal-nav" data-section-resized>...</div>
```

So simple fix, but that isn't in the zurb documentation - does anyone one know what that attribute is for?

Comment: ask them on twitter @foundationzurb or github. they are usually pretty good about responding.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. The above answer didn't quite work for me because all my tabs were squashed to the top right, overlapping each other.

This thread helped me sort it out:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3555

> This isn't broken. Sizing can't be calculated correctly when elements aren't visible. If you're going to hide them and then show, you'll need to call reflow or fire the resize event to get things to calculate the correct sizes.

At least for my case, my items were being loaded AFTER Foundation was able to calculate the widths, so it always went to 0.

Hope this helps!